# pandas add new rows to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this

```
A    B    C
1    2    3
4    5    6
```

I want to add new rows to my dataframe in a forloop (not looping the existing dataframe)

```
for item in queryset:
    if item == 'foo':
        #append new row, with only column 'b' with value
        df.append({'b' : item} , ignore_index=True)
```

But this method does not work. How could I add a new row to my existing dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

append return a dataframe and does not modify the dataframe. So you should do :

```
df = df.append({'b' : item} , ignore_index=True)
```